# the world of the scientific (is this idiomatic?)

Tags: adjectives

> the world of the scientific

I think the young=young people but can't understnad if 'the + scientific' also makes any meaning right.

Comment: "I think the young=young people" is unclear. Can this be said differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [I] can't understnad if 'the + scientific' also makes any meaning

Yes, we can use "the scientific" to refer to all scientific things, although it's not a particularly common usage.

For example,

> Within the realm of the scientific, Galileo's heliocentric cosmology has become universally accepted.

Answer (score 1):

While possible, it is not particular idiomatic. There is a perfectly good word "science" that could be used in this context and would normally be preferred:

> The World of Science